# GAS でLINEBOT作成

Tags: google-apps-script, line

#### 前提

GASでLINE公式に特定のワードを受信したらflexメッセージで返したい

#### 実現したいこと

- [ ] GASを使用してflexで返信したい

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
失敗しました（詳しいのは見れませんでした。）
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
// LINEチャネルのアクセストークン
const LINE_TOKEN = 'アクセストークン'; // ここに「チャネルアクセストークン」を貼りつけます
const LINE_URL = 'https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/reply';

//postリクエストを受取ったときに発火する関数
function doPost(e) {

//ここで天気や運行状況を取得

//メッセージ送信↓↓↓↓↓
  const event = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).events[0];
  // LINE返信用のトークン
  const replyToken = event.replyToken;
  // ユーザーのメッセージを取得
  const userMessage = event.message.text;

  // 応答メッセージの内容
  let messages = [];
  if (userMessage === "天気") {
    //問診テンプレート
    messages = [
      {
        type: 'flex',
            altText:"天気予報",
            contents:{flexメッセージの内容}
      }
    ];
  } else if (userMessage === "運行情報") {
    messages = [
      {
        type: 'flex',
            altText:"運行情報",
            contents: {flexメッセージの内容}
},
      },
    ];
  } else {
   
  }
  //lineで返答する
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(LINE_URL, {
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${LINE_TOKEN}`,
    },
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': JSON.stringify({
      'replyToken': replyToken,
      'messages': messages,
    }),
  });
  ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'content': 'post ok' })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

#### 試したこと

何を試したらいいのかわからなかったです。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Qiita・teratailでも同様の質問をしています。

参考サイト：[せこしょーさん](https://sskshogo.com/2022/10/28/1255/)

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/8qce3gffix3wi2) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとう御座います。

Comment: アクセストークンは貼り付けた上で実行しましたか？

Comment: 提示されたソースコードを実行した場合に、「 `失敗しました（詳しいのは見れませんでした。）` 」というエラーが表示されるのでしょうか？ / [ログ]([Class Logger  |  Apps Script  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger))の見方がわからない、という段階でしょうか

Comment: teratail で解決済みのようです。